# How to install GPU drivers in a ryzen/vega + nvidia laptop with Fedora?

Tags: fedora, nvidia, gpu, amd, hybrid-graphics

I'm a newbie and trying to get my machine working properly in Linux, my Native language is not English so I apologize in advance for any grammar errors. I installed Fedora in my laptop:

ASUS FX505D
CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3550H with Radeon Vega Mobile Gfx
GPU: nvidia GTX 1650

I tried several distros so far and attempted to install either bumblebee or prime, but I'm seriously lost here.
How should I proceed about this?